# How to add custimized context menu item on right click in browser window?

Tags: browser, contextmenu, custom-contextmenu

[image]

Here I want to add my custom menu option i.e. ColorZilla, Aptana Studio on web browser right click

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this with a browser plugin.  Each browser will have its own syntax for plugins and specifically adding context menu items.

Answer (score 0):

Aleks G. is right you cannot do that directly within the browser.

I don't know if it can help you or if it is what you are looking for but, within the browser you can handle the right click interaction in order to display your own custom menu ( not a particular menu item but the full menu ) ... meaning the default browser menu won't get displayed at all.

In case you are interested, you can have a small sample [here](http://elouai.com/javascript/javascript-popup-menu.php)